# New Web Dev person and need help on GitHub

Tags: github

I am new to GitHub and having issues uploading a website.....

When I upload to GitHub, it separates folders ([Here is the image of what I am seeing GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HCFA.png)) and thus website doesn't display properly.

Here is the image of the file on my computer [Here is what I am seeing on computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnbXj.png)

I attached screenshots, any help would be great....

I am confused af at this point in time

Comment: have you used Drag and Drop feature to upload the file?

Comment: I reorganized your repository per the images the best i could. If you merge this hopefully it'll get you back on track: https://github.com/ashton8504/Ohio-GitHub-Upload/pull/1

Answer (score 0):

Try To push changes correctly as it doesn't happen usually. Read this:
Open your Command prompt first then move to the particular which here contains your whole website.
Start with

1. git init (it will initialize your folder to be pushed up or pulled
   to git Controls)
2. then git add . (To add All the files create your
   .gitignore file carefully)
3. git commit -m "Whatever you want to write
   us a note about the changes"
4. then git push -u origin main

Hope Your problem will be solved or maybe something you can only diagnose because you are there sitting and functioning
**Note If there is any folder containing called .git, delete that. Before proceeding the way I mentioned **

Comment: I tried this, when it get to ```git add .``` it states "error:

'Ohio-Website/' does not have a commit checked out"

then states:

"fatal: adding files failed"

Any tips there?

Also, thank you for your response

Comment: first commit then try to add or just delete the .git folder and start things from scratch

Comment: https://zjschulz.medium.com/error-does-not-have-a-commit-checked-out-573c0ed9c49 Refer here as he states that you are using frontend and backend together just separate them